# Live preview markdown editor

Tags: user-controls, markdown

Forgive me if this is has been answered. I have looked around, but didn't find anything.

I am creating a site for non-techies and it requires them to be able to add rich text content. I have been looking at Markdown for this, and would like to use that.

I have been searching around for a nice (jquery) ui control to make editing simple, but everything I have looked at has the live preview living somewhere else on the page other than the input box. ([WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) is like this, [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/markdown/), etc..)

I would like to use something that makes it feel like you are using a word processor. Like how [TinyMCe](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) does it, but running on Markdown, not HTML

Is there anything like that, or maybe somewhere that shows how to build it?

---

To clarify, I'm looking for an editor that makes it feel like you are typing in the live preview; not a textbox with a preview above/below.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - Markdown (the markup language) is its own user interface - and HTML is a much better backend for a word-processor-like experience IMO.  Or are you thinking of something where you edit markdown and see a live preview of the content? (like f. ex. the SO answer interface)

Comment: Yes, like how SO does it only I don't want them to feel like they are editing a text box with a preview below. More like using Word, but Markdown is what is being generated not Html. Does that help?

Comment: So, you need something that converts HTML to markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found something that I love. the [Pen editor on Github](http://sofish.github.io/pen/) does just what I wanted. I am glad to see someone has taken this on

Answer (score 5):

If I get what you're looking for, then the simplest approach would be to generate HTML with [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), then apply something like [Markdownify](http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/) to the output of e.g., `tinymce.getContent()`.

Comment: I just looked into the Markdownify source. It seems like a fun little project to convert it to a TinyMCE plugin. If there's real interest in this, I'd be happy to spend a bit of time. (I've authored a ton of TinyMCE plugins at work.)

Comment: not the most elegant thing, but it would work. I would rather not have the bounty wasted, so you can have it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Stack Edit](https://stackedit.io/editor#) It's a great WYSIWYG markdown editor - syncs with Google Docs, Dropbox & CouchDB, publishes to Github (and many other places), and offers easy link sharing. You can access it on their website or using the Chrome app. You can create titles and lists in the editor there, and it will show you the corresponding text in markdown format. You can then save, publish, share, or download the file.

Answer (score -4):

Markdown would not be compatible with a WYSIWYG editor. Consider this sample Markdown:

```
Let's link to [Google][].

  [Google]: http://www.google.com/
```

If you were making a WYSIWYG editor, what would happen after you typed `[Google]`? Would you see blue underlined text? Would you just see `[Google]` since it's not a valid hyperlink yet? What about after you type the trailing `[]`? It's still not a fully-defined hyperlink; you can't click it, because Markdown doesn't know where it links.

And how does the user type that `[Google]: http://www.google.com/` follow-up line? That line isn't displayed; it's markup; it's invisible. Where do you type invisible text into a WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: SO provides a preview, right? Just below the input box. I would *like* it to feel like you are editing in the preview. I know there are challenges, and that is why I probably couldn't find one. Doesn't mean they can't be solved.

Comment: And (Since it is for non-techies) I could just make them use the toolbar for formatting, right? So they just type `Lets link to Google` highlight `Google`, click the link button, and provide a Url.

Comment: If you're going to ignore the Markdown aspects of Markdown, then why do you care about it being Markdown? Sounds like a WYSIWYG editor for HTML would serve you just as well.

Comment: From my experience, most WYSIWYG editors that use HTML create terrible syntax, and I would like complete control over how it is generated. Also, I would (eventually) like to have an option for more advanced users to be able to switch to "raw" mode.